# Android app and Django server communciation: using json

Tags: android, json, django

I am working on an app that involves exchange of data between the android app and django server. I am able to send data in json via http post. But I am not able to decode the json in my django code(views.py). I am working on apps for the first time. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit you JSON data as a serializeArray, it should be a Python dict in your request.POST in your views.py. So you can use something like:

```
    def this_view(request):
         if request.method == POST:
               data_you_want = request.POST['key']
               return HttpResponse(json.dumps(some_data_back_to_the_page), content_type='application/json')
         else:
               return render(request,'some.html')
```

Comment: Pls see my response below

Answer (score 0):

Steven, I modified the code as show below:
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

```
@csrf_exempt
def hello(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("get")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST['GrpName']
        return HttpResponse("success")
```

When I run my app on the android emulator, in the toast message I am receiving html source code instead of "success"

Comment: Hi, you may need to post some of you html code...I am not quite sure how you send you json data there.